# how to determine the relationship of two time series?

Tags: regression, time-series, cross-correlation

The relationship here means: the occurrence of one time series increase(boost) or decrease(suppress) the values of another time series.

Is there any statistical model or method that can do this kind of task?

Specifically, I have two time series, which is the number of retweets of two different memes (hashtags) at different time. I want to know if the existence of one meme has some influence on the other meme? The influence can be promoting the other one or suppressing.

I did find a model in ecology, which is the [Lotka–Volterra equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations). But it seems it does not provide a effective algorithm to determine this types of relationship.

Comment: Can you say more about your situation, your data, & your goals?

Comment: @gung The post has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

You could have shown us some plots of your series ... start with calculating cross-correlations, the lag maximizing the cross-correlations tell you something about which series are leading/lagging the other.  You could look into time series regression, see [What's the difference between Time Series Regression and Forecasting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/433073/whats-the-difference-between-time-series-regression-and-forecasting).